# Populate a form with a model object after redirecting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a basic CRUD structure for a model that works well. Now I want to redirect to the create method and populate the form with a pre-existing model. It would work by a user selecting an id and then I would select that model and redirect to the create page and populate the form.

This is what I have tried so far

```
$order = Orders::find($id);

$inventory = Inventory::where(['id' => $order->inventory_id])->first()->toArray();

return redirect()->route('backend.inventory.create', $inventory['bag_id'])->withInput($inventory);
```

In the above example, it finds the order and selects the single inventory item related to it (I have confirmed that it's definitely selecting an inventory item as expected) and redirects to the inventory creation page. However, when using the ->withInput() method this doesn't seem to populate my form with the data as I expected.

How do I pass data to a form using a redirect?

---

Adding the form code as requested below. This is just one column of the form as its a huge block of code

```
<div class="form-group row" id="item-name" v-if="type != '3'">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Item Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your `backend.inventory.create` file look like?

Comment: You can simply use compact method and change 
 

    return redirect()->route('backend.inventory.create', $inventory['bag_id'])->withInput($inventory); to
     return redirect()->route('backend.inventory.create', $inventory['bag_id'])->with(compact('inventory'));

Comment: @zlatan I've added the code for part of the view, the form is massive so I've only included part of it

Comment: withInput() is used for redirects not during returning a view page.

Comment: @Oops isn't that what my code is doing? It's doing a redirect? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I have added an answer. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

If you're using Form Request Validation, this is exactly how Laravel will redirect you back with errors and the given input.

Excerpt from **\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests**:

```
return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                    ->withInput($request->input())
                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
```

Comment: I have no input, I'm redirecting with a pre-existing model from the database, not redirecting with form input.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
<div class="form-group row" id="item-name" v-if="type != '3'">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Item Name</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') ?? $inventory['name'] }}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

`{{ old('name') ?? ($inventory['name'] ?? '') }}` if old data is present it will show old data otherwise `$inventory->name` which is coming from withInput with is also optional that's why i put ??

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#old-input

Answer (score 0):

You can use **compact()** function  that creates array containing variables and their values.

```
$order = Orders::find($id);
$inventory = Inventory::where(['id' => $order->inventory_id])->first()->toArray();
return view('backend.inventory.create', compact('inventory'));
```

In your view page you can use it like,

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $inventory['name'] }}" required>
```