# Laravel populate form with cloned model data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, clone

I'm implementing a "Clone" button in my application, which should allow to perform the following:

1. create a copy of the chosen model;
2. redirect to the `create` view, whose form field should be populated with the cloned model's data;
3. allow the user edit some fields;
4. save the new model.

So far, my `ModelController@clone` method is:

```
$newModel = $existingModel->replicate();
$newModel->title = "Copy of ".$existingModel->title;
$newModel->created_at = now() // not sure if necessary, or if it'll be changed once the model is stored in the database

return redirect(route('models.create')); // I know this doesn't do what I need
```

As it is, obviously, nothing gets passed to the `create` view, but I can't find any clue on how to do that.

I have tried adding `->withInput(compact($newModel))` to the `redirect()` call, but I don't see the field being populated.

In the `models.create` view, I have set up the form field to use the `old(...)` data, if available.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60003580) answer is almost what I need, but it would imply changing every field to check if there is some sort of input other than the `old` session data, like this:

```
<input [other attributes omitted] value="{{ $newModel['title'] ?? old('title') }}">
```

Is it the right way to do so, or is there a quicker/more standardized way of proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could overriding the session old input data by:

```
Session::put('_old_input', $newModel);
```

and then just render the `old()` in form inputs

Comment: Didn't know that the `old` values could be created "artificially" like this. Had to tweak a few things involving relationships in order to make it work, but now it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ...